# How can I filter DRF serializer HyperlinkedRelationField queryset based on request data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have my users account authority stored in `request.session.get('authority')`

At the moment the endpoint in DRFs web-browsable HTML representation is showing all the addresses of all accounts in the html form. Which I'd expect as I'm querying all the addresses.

[image: Screenshot of DRF form]
Screenshot of DRF form: addresses are displaying their authority.uuid, they should only show the current authorities address data.

**Company Serializer**

```
# ToDo: filter queryset objects
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    clients = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name='client-detail',
        queryset=Client.objects.all()
    )
    addresses = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name='address-detail',
        queryset=Address.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'url', 'clients', 'addresses')
        read_only_fields = ('authority',)
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
addresses = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name='address-detail',
        queryset=Address.objects.filter(authority=request.session.get('authority'))
    )
```

But not sure there is a way to access the request data in the serializer when I'm setting up the HyperlinkedRelatedField.

Perhaps I'm approaching this in entirely the wrong way. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Many thanks to Enthusiast Martin, based on his answer this is how I've implemented it for now:

```
def hyperlinkedRelatedFieldByAuthority(model, view_name, authority):
    return serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        view_name=view_name,
        queryset=model.objects.filter(authority=authority)
    )

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()

        authority = self.context['request'].session.get('authority')
        fields['clients'] = hyperlinkedRelatedFieldByAuthority(Client, 'client-detail', authority)
        fields['addresses'] = hyperlinkedRelatedFieldByAuthority(Address, 'address-detail', authority)

        return fields
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override serializer's get_fields method and update the addresses queryset.

You can access the request via serializer's context

Something like this:

```
def get_fields(self):
    fields = super().get_fields()

    request = self.context['request']

    fields['addresses'].queryset = ** your queryset using request data **

    return fields
```